# Xcode pop up menu, how to create action based of selection (EASY)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, popupmenu

I am trying to make the pop up menu such that as long as the selection is not the default "University", then UniversityLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen, otherwise if the section is still on default then the UniversityLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed

That's it!

**Pop Up Menu Code**

```
func UniPop(){
        let Uni = {
            (action: UIAction) in
            print(action.title)
        }
        University.menu = UIMenu(children: [
            UIAction(title: "University of Warwick", handler: Uni),
            UIAction(title: "University", state: .on, handler: Uni)
        ])
        University.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        University.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        
        if let uni = University.menu?.selectedElements.first?.title

        {
            if let errorMessage = InvalidUni(uni)
            {
                UniversityLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed
                UniversityLabel.text = errorMessage
            }
            else {
                UniversityLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            }
        }
        checkForValidForm()
    }
    

        func InvalidUni(_ value: String) -> String?
    {
        let reqularExpression = "University"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", reqularExpression)
        if !predicate.evaluate(with: value)
        {
            return "."
        }
        return nil
        }
```

I tried creating a regex function:

```
        func InvalidUni(_ value: String) -> String?
    {
        let reqularExpression = "University"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", reqularExpression)
        if !predicate.evaluate(with: value)
        {
            return "."
        }
        return nil
        }
```

if the University.menu?.selectedElements.first?.title = "University",then UniversityLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemRed.

Currently, when I run the code UniversityLabel.textColor = UIColor.systemGreen, even when another option is selected from the pop menu.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you post should be able to be built in its own project as is, unless the question is why it won't build. Looking at the code, however, I suspect you have greatly overcomplicated the logic here. You probably only need to use a `ternary`, unless you have need of the color in other places.